# Angular Dropdown functionality

Tags: angular

I have a request to make a dropdown work as the following:

Say we have a dropdown of States.

Ex: When I type letters "OK" or "OKLA" or any match I would like the dropdown to select Oklahoma.

The behavior I am currently facing chooses Ohio then goes to Kansas, etc.

What functionality can I add that will continue to find a match and not search for the first letter in the dropdown at each key stroke?

Thanks!

```
   <mat-form-field class="state-dropdown pad">
              <mat-label>State</mat-label>
              <mat-select [(ngModel)]="stateValue" name="stateDropdown" required id="ddnState">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let StateData of StateDropdownData" [value]="StateData.State_Cde">
                  {{ StateData.State_Cde }}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please attach your code, then we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Posted the HTML - thanks! - and the behavior isn't wrong its just not what the users want.  The current behavior is default for most websites dropdown features.

Comment: can you provide the code for filtering? couldn't see the filter logic in the provided snippet?

Comment: The filtering code is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like Angular Material's [Autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component will be better suited for your purpose?

Comment: Awesome!  This saved the day - https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview